# "cannot assemble. reversed route is not specified"

Tags: php, zend-framework, router

I had problem with the error from Zend Framework 1.9 when was building routers for friendly url`s. Te error was:

> cannot assemble. reversed route is not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not so easy to find the solution, so i want to share if anyone will struggle with this like me.

Like they wrote in zend manual:
"Since regex patterns are not easily reversed, you will need to prepare a reverse URL if you wish to use a URL helper or even an assemble method of this class. This reversed path is represented by a string parsable by sprintf() and is defined as a fourth construct parameter:"

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'archive/(\d+)',
    array( ... ),
    array('year' => 1),
    'archive/%s'
);
```

So basically all You have to do is to add

```
'archive/%s'
```

line to Your router params.

I found the solution in this thread

[Zend community thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Using-url-view-helper-with-regex-route-td660695.html)